# Creating new Dimension and Segment to create a new chart

Tags: experience-analytics

I am trying to create a new dimension and a new segment to use in my new chart. After many attempts I found this article **[Create an interaction processor](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/processing/interaction-aggregation/create-an-interaction-processor.html)**-

From this reference I did the following steps:

- Create dimension class and table
- Creating a dimension class
- Creating a dimension table
- Create fact class and table
- Creating a fact class
- Creating a fact table
- Create an interaction aggregation processor class
- Add processor to configuration

After it, I deployed the code and then I created my **"By UserAgent" Flexible Dimension** and create the Segment, as showed in the following figure:

[image: By UserAgent Flexible Dimension]

My **UserAgentChart** is configured this way

[image: UserAgentChart - Data]

In my dashboard I saw an error

[image]

Note: I know when I create a Segment I need to deploy and I need to way 30min, after this time the data start to be processed.

**Are these steps correct? I am doing something wrong? Why I have an error?**

***UPDATE 1:***

From logs i got this

> ERROR [Experience Analytics]:
>   SegmentProcessor failed to process interaction
>   'b1d329f5-1c8a-0000-0000-056780e07875' segment
>   '3a60eaea-0ac5-42c7-947b-f5e53ea87bac' -
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Dimension could not be resolved for
>   for dimension id: 8dae1809-f370-4997-adf8-64107cee49a6    at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Data.Model.AggregationSegment.get_Dimension()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Data.Model.AggregationSegment.GetData(IVisitAggregationContext
>   context)    at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.SegmentProcessor.ProcessSegments(IInteractionAggregationContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 segments)

**UPDATE 2:**

New issue - [why analytics were not stored?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/why-analytics-were-not-stored)

Comment: If there is a server error, there should be exception in the log files. Can you see what it is?

Comment: Configuring the new Segment with Sitecore Rocks can be a bit tricky. This article explains how in a good level of detail. Did you follow those steps? https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-use-dimensions-segments-sitecore-xanalytics-powerful-rohit-chopra

Comment: This is also a good read that deals with setting up the segment in the Dashboard through Sitecore Rocks: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/ramon-aseniero/posts/creating-a-custom-report-on-sitecore-cms-v8-2

Comment: Just updated it with the log - this dimension is a flexibledimension and it is not a imension.... but It is not clear to me.

Comment: Is {8dae1809-f370-4997-adf8-64107cee49a6} the new Dimension you created? Did you publish it? Did you patch the config at <sitecore><experienceAnalytics><aggregation><dimensions> with the ID and type of your Dimension?

Comment: My new dimension are not configured in web config <sitecore><experienceAnalytics><aggregation><dimensions> - that is one problem

Comment: in my first attempt I used this article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-use-dimensions-segments-sitecore-xanalytics-powerful-rohit-chopra/ but it uses dimension...